# javascritp window.onload api call through attached script

Tags: javascript

I have a script like

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        function handleAction() {
          var win = window.open('https://example.com', "_blank");
          var script = document.createElement('script');
          script.src = 'http://myassets.com/example.js';
          win.document.head.appendChild(script);

        }
        window.onload = handleAction
    </script>
```

Here I have attached an "example.js" script to the newly opened window. The script contains one simple log API call.

But when my page is loaded "example.js" is removed from the dom and it can not make API call. When page loads if contains page dom and remove the "example.js"

Is there any way I can make an API call from the attached script ??

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you would like to open a new window and load a script on that opened window?

Your current code will simply not work as it does not have access to the opened window's DOM, only the current DOM from which it is being called from.

The only way this will work is if you have control over the code for the site you want to open, and put the `onload` event there and if you want that to run on some specific condition, consider using a query parameter.

Otherwise, you cannot inject your own JavaScript programmatically and make an API call on a website that doesn't belong to you (this is reaching unethical territory).

Comment: I can execute javascript code.. its just api call takes time and before that original dom is loaded and my script is removed